# Noncompactness of the closed unit ball in $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

Let 
$$
L^2[0,1]=\{f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R\,\,\text{such that}\,\, \|f\|_2<∞\},
$$ 
where $\|f\|_2^2=\int_0^1 |f(x)|^2\,dx.$ Show that the unit sphere 
$$
S=\{f\in L^2[0,1]:\|f\|_2\le 1\}, 
$$
is closed and bounded, but not compact.

Conclude that if $G\subset L^2[0,1]$ has nonempty interior, then it cannot be compact.

Comment: The title is *very* uninformative. "Noncompacity of unit ball in $L^2$" is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions
$$
u_n(x)=\sqrt{2}\sin 2\pi nx,\,\,n\in\mathbb N,
$$
belong to $S$ and 
$$
\|u_m-u_n\|_2=\sqrt{2}, \quad\text{for every $m\ne n$}.
$$
Hence, $\{u_n\}$ does not have any converging subsequence.

*Conclusion.* If $G^\circ$ is nont empty, then there exists $x_0\in L^2[0,1]$ and $r>0$, such that $\overline{B(x_0,r)}\subset G$. But $\overline{B(x_0,r)}$ is not compact, and so is not $G$.

Comment: Thanks, I really don't know how to find the example, it seems that orthonomal basis would work